# DBSCAN (with metric only) in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

I have objects and a distance function, and want to cluster these using `DBSCAN` method in `scikit-learn`. My objects don't have a representation in Euclidean space. I know, that it is possible to use`precomputed` metric, but in my case it's very impractical, due to large size of distance matrix. Is there any way to overcome this in `scikit-learn`?   Maybe, are there another python implementations of DBSCAN that can do so?

Comment: Why don't you want to use metric parameter in constructor?

Comment: Following @Olologin's comment, `metric` parameter in the constructor of DBSCAN accepts either a string (for an already implemented distances) or a callable (a function that for a given 2 elements, returns a distance measure). Write your own and initialize DBSCAN with `metric=my_func`.

Answer (score 8):

scikit-learn has support for a large variety of metrics.

Some of them can be accelerated using the kdtree (very fast), using the ball tree (fast), using precomputed distance matrixes (fast, but needs a lot of memory) or no precomputation but Cython implementations (quadratic runtime) or even python callbacks (very slow).

This last option that is implemented but extremely slow:

```
def mydistance(x,y):
  return numpy.sum((x-y)**2)

labels = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=minpts, metric=mydistance).fit_predict(X)
```

is, unfortunately, much much much much slower than

```
labels = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=minpts, metric='euclidean').fit_predict(X)
```

I found ELKI to perform much better when you need to use your own distance functions. Java can compile them into near native code speed using the Hotspot JNI compiler. Python (currently) cannot do this.

Comment: I don't think DBSCAN will work with user defined metric such as 'mydistance'. The documentation says:  If metric is a string or callable, it must be one of the options allowed by metrics.pairwise.calculate_distance for its metric parameter.

Comment: It works (otherwise, why would they mention "callable"). I used it. It's just really slow because of the python interpreter compared to the Cython metrics.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own distance code ref the top answer, just as it says, it was extremely slow, the built-in distance code was much better. I'm wondering how to speed up.